# Why Is Xcode Throwing Errors But Still Compiling?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an iOS app that is using Firebase Firestore. In the project I am working on, I am receiving a number of errors related to Firebase Firestore code. When I create a new project and use the same code the errors do not exist. What's odd is that the code builds and compiles even with the errors. A simple example of what is happening is below.

User.swift

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import MapKit

struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

UserRepository.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class UserRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }

func startSnapshotListener() {
        // Add a SnapshotListener to the User Collection.
        db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Check to make sure the Collection contains Documents
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No Users.")
                    return
                }
                
                // Documents exist.
                self.users = documents.compactMap { user in
                    do {
                        //return try user.data(with: User.self)
                        return try user.data(as: User.self)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }

func createUser1() {
        let user1 = testUser1
        
        do {
            let _ = try self.db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).document("testUser1").setData(from: user1)
        } catch {
            print("Error writing new User to Firestore in SeafoodRepository: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are coming from

```
return try user.data(as: User.self)
```

> Error1: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
>
> Error2: Cannot convert return expression of type '[String: Any]' to return
> type'User?'

and

```
let _ = try self.db.collection(FirestoreCollection.users).document("testUser1").setData(from: user1)
```

> Error1: Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type'[String: Any]'

I've cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, etc and nothing quiets the errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's fairly common in my experience. Especially when you `SwiftGen`, `pod install`, etc. As you probably know, Xcode although nice to use when it works well, is pretty buggy. I believe this is a similar bug as well. It doesn't quiet those errors for a while in my experience either. I just let Xcode silence the errors itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my version of Firebase. I am using Swift Package Manager to manage Firebase. I thought this updated automatically. It doesn't.

File -> Swift Packages -> Update to Latest Package Versions

This silenced the errors.